# reading from a file (c programing)

Tags: c, file

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4
#define A_INPUT "agents.txt"

typedef struct
{
    long id;
    char lastName[20];
    char name[20];
    char type;
    int workHours;
    long managId;
    int sell[10];
} Agents;

Agents AgArr[N]={0};

void main()
{
    int i,j=1;
    FILE*agents;
    agents=fopen(A_INPUT,"r");

    if(agents == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit();
    }

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        fscanf(agents, "%ld", &AgArr[i].id);
        fscanf(agents, "%s", &AgArr[i].lastName);
        fscanf(agents, "%s", &AgArr[i].name);
        fscanf(agents, "%c", &AgArr[i].type);
        fscanf(agents, "%d", &AgArr[i].workHours);
        fscanf(agents, "%ld", &AgArr[i].managId);
    } 
}
```

This is the text file im reading from:

```
045654987 Cohen Yael P 135 302546887
024587891 Cohen Rafi F 150 -1
306354487 Gabai Shai P 112 302546887
302546887 Benzur Gadi M 130 -1
```

The problem is that the array is not getting all the text, I get spaces and 0.
How do I scan it properly ?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux).

Answer (score 3):

You need to *read carefully* the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) (and read it twice).

Then understand why you need sometimes spaces in `fscanf` format strings, perhaps

```
    if (fscanf(agents," %ld %s",&AgArr[i].id, &AgArr[i].lastName)==2) {
```

(actually it can be and probably should be even more; you could have a single but long `fscanf` call with a half-dozen of arguments, but you should test the result of `fscanf`).

And you should test the result of `fscanf` it is meaningful.

Your `for` loop probably should be

```
 for (i=0; !feof(agents) && i<10; i++)
```

And I believe you should name your `FILE*` variable with a name reminding it is some file (not a set of agents), e.g. `agf` or `agents_file` instead of `agents`